# How long can we set the Ajax timeout to be?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a scenario where an ajax request takes anywhere from 5-10 minutes to be processed on the server side.

One solution is to keep polling from javascript to see if the request has completed. I was wondering if i could take the simpler route by making just the one ajax call & setting the ajax timeout to 15 minutes & getting intimated when the request gets completed.

Is it fine to set the ajax timeout that long? How long is fine?

I am not concerned with the user experience. The only requirement is, i get a response back reliably as long as my connection is active.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the webserver and possibly any proxy servers in-between. Ergo: you can't really know. The safest is polling. That also handles disconnect issues in the 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Tomcat on the server side & ExtJS on the client. I had run a few tests & it ran fine. Had doubts on how reliable it would be.

Comment: Well, as long as you try reconnects on the client if it loses the connection you should be fine.

Comment: I get polling is safer. The problem with keeping the connection open that long with my proposed method is it might get disconnected. But this problem is also prevalent in methods like long polling (Push protocols) where the http Connection is kept open for a longer duration of time. So, is my proposed approach any different that what long polling does. Long polling is used quite a lot nowadays & i haven't heard about the connection loss issues when dealing with it.